# How to edit mobile view of my wordpress website without affecting the desktop view?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, static-website

Im building a woocommerce store and im almost done with it. Now Im trying to make a few changes to the tab and mobile version but it automatically causes changes to the desktop version too which is a bit stupid. My mobile version looks bad compared to my desktop version. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

How are you editing your CSS? You can use media queries to set which screen size you want your css to be applicable to:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp